# How to wait until e-mail is sent and window is closed in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

My VBA code opens an e-mail template and should copy the email content into an appointment after editing and sending the e-mail.

The problem is that the appointment opens before the e-mail is sent, and the unedited e-mail content is inserted into the appointment. (if I remove the while loop)

How can I wait for sending the e-mail and closing its window?

Error: Outlook freezes or it displays the error:

> runtime error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': element moved....

```
Public Sub Fooo()
Dim items As Outlook.items
Dim Item As Object

Set items = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.items

Set Item = items.Add("IPM.Note.My Template Mail")
Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
Item.Display

While Item.Sent = False
Wend

CreateAppointment MyMail:=Item

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `DoEvents` inside of the loop `While Item.Sent = False`. Can you please add your code for `CreateAppointment`?

Comment: Adding `DoEvents` prevents Outlook from freezing. I think adding `CreateAppointment` would be too much code in the question and it has nothing do to with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify a bit your `CreateAppointment` sub,
but use a variable to store the content of the mail before sending it and then pass it to your sub!

```
Public Sub Fooo()
Dim items As Outlook.items
Dim Item As Object
Dim ItmContent As String

Set items = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.items

Set Item = items.Add("IPM.Note.My Template Mail")

With Item
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
    .Display True

    Do
        ItmContent = .Body 'Or other property that you use in CreateAppointment
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Item Is Nothing
End With 'Item

CreateAppointment ItmContent

End Sub
```

Working solution with error handling :

```
Public Sub Fooo()
Dim items As Outlook.items
Dim Item As Object
Dim ItmContent As String

Set items = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.items

Set Item = items.Add("IPM.Note.My Template Mail")

Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
Item.Display

On Error GoTo MailSent
    Do
        ItmContent = Item.Body 'Or other property that you use in CreateAppointment
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Item Is Nothing
On Error GoTo 0


DoEvents
AfterSend:
    'Debug.Print ItmContent
    CreateAppointment ItmContent
    Exit Sub
MailSent:
    If Err.Number <> -2147221238 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Resume AfterSend
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the same error again: runtime error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': element moved....

Comment: @foobarbaz : On which line?

Comment: Randomly `While .Sent = False` or `ItmContent = .Body`

Comment: @foobarbaz : My bad, just need to make the test at the end of the loop! ;) Try the edit

Comment: I get the same error again on line: `Loop While .Sent = False`

Comment: @foobarbaz : I added a boolean to store the value of `.Sent`, try it

Comment: Does not work, again the same error. `Item.Sent` is never `true`. At the beginning its `false` after the mail was sent, `Item.Sent` is undefined

Comment: @foobarbaz Last chance, after that I guess, you'll have to use `Application_ItemSend` event to set the variables `ItmContent` and `IsSent`...

Comment: Doesn't work, error in line: `Loop Until IsSent = False Or IsSent Is Nothing` types are incompatible

Comment: @foobarbaz : My bad, a boolean would indeed cause an issue with `Is Nothing`!

Comment: This will never work - as soon as the message is submitted, the only allowed operation is to release your reference to it. The Sent property will never turn to true - the message in the Sent Items folder is physically different from the message you are displaying.

Comment: @foobarbaz : I got rid of the `.Sent` to use only `Item`, give it a try! ;)

Comment: @foobarbaz : Got it to work with error handling! ;) Enjoy!

Comment: yeah, with error handling it works now, thank you! :-)

Comment: @foobarbaz : Glad I could help! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the Items.ItemAdd event to fire on the Sent Items folder and only then create the new appointment.

Comment: How should be the code for this?

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?